# Multiple Views in Paging Adapter Not Showing First Item When No items From Paging Data

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a paging adapter that looks like this (the parent comment is the first view and the replies are the second view):

```
class RepliesAdapter(private val listener: OnItemClickListener) :
    PagingDataAdapter<RepliesResponse, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(
        REPLIES_COMPARATOR
    ) {

    private var parentCommentResponse: CommentsResponse? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return when (viewType) {
            VIEW_TYPE_PARENT_COMMENT -> {
                val binding = ParentReplyCommentBinding.inflate(
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                    parent,
                    false
                )
                ParentReplyCommentViewHolder(binding)
            }

            VIEW_TYPE_REPLIES -> {
                val binding =
                    ItemCommentsBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
                RepliesViewHolder(binding)
            }

            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown view type: $viewType")
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (holder.itemViewType) {
            VIEW_TYPE_PARENT_COMMENT -> {
                val parentReplyCommentViewHolder = holder as RepliesAdapter.ParentReplyCommentViewHolder
                getItem(position)
                parentReplyCommentViewHolder.bind(this.parentCommentResponse!!)
            }

            VIEW_TYPE_REPLIES -> {
                val currentItem = getItem(position) as RepliesResponse
                val repliesHolder = holder as RepliesAdapter.RepliesViewHolder
                repliesHolder.bind(currentItem)
            }

            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown view type: ${holder.itemViewType}")
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        Log.e("position", position.toString())
        return if (position == 0 && parentCommentResponse != null) {
            VIEW_TYPE_PARENT_COMMENT
        } else {
            VIEW_TYPE_REPLIES
        }
    }
```

Then binding happens and then I have a companion object that looks like this within the adapter:

```
companion object {
    private val REPLIES_COMPARATOR = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<RepliesResponse>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(
            oldItem: RepliesResponse,
            newItem: RepliesResponse
        ) = oldItem.id == newItem.id

        override fun areContentsTheSame(
            oldItem: RepliesResponse,
            newItem: RepliesResponse
        ) = oldItem == newItem
    }

    private const val VIEW_TYPE_PARENT_COMMENT = 0
    private const val VIEW_TYPE_REPLIES = 1
}
```

In the fragment, this is how I create the adapter and provide it with the data:

```
val adapter = RepliesAdapter(this)
parentCommentResponse = args.commentsResponse
adapter.setParentComment(parentCommentResponse)

viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    viewModel.commentReplies.collect {
        adapter.submitData(it)
    }
}
```

However, when there are no replies...the parent comment does not show. When there are replies, the parent comment shows, but the first reply never shows. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Same with my case.  @user2896120 Have you got the solution?